# mysql.connector.errors.NotSupportedError: Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' is not supported shown in exe only

Tags: python, mysql, pyinstaller, mysql-connector-python

I have a python program problem. When I test my program(using PyQt5 and mysql-connector-python) in PyCharm, it works totally fine and I am able to connect to my SQL server and also read/write data in database. but when I use pyinstaller to create the .exe and try to run it, the application(.exe created by pyinstaller) close at once. The error shows that:[error01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmXHa.jpg)

Here is my pyinstaller command:

`pyinstaller --onefile School_booking_system.py`

Line 60 in  mentioned in cmd-screen error message:

```
bookingdb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="username",
    password="password",
    database='database',
    auth_plugin='mysql_native_password'
)
```

I am using MySQL 8.0 and Python 3.8.
Can anyone else help me to spot the problem?

Comment: Can you please add the output of `$ pip freeze` to your question so we can see the packages you are attempting to compile with pyinstaller.

Comment: the screenshot is here: https://ibb.co/1JSj0k6 please let me know if I was doing it wrong.

Comment: can you please also add the version of mysql and python you are using with your mysql python connector.

Comment: i am using MySQL 8.0 and Python 3.8.

Answer (score -1):

Change the interpreter to the one downloaded from python.org